# Reach another class' property in c#

Tags: c#

I am sorry, if this is a dumb question but I am only a beginner and might not have covered this in class. 
I have a dogsNames class with name and id property and have a dogs class with other data and an id property. I need to make calculations on information in dog class but I need to return the name of the dog which is in the dogsName class and I only have the id for it. How Will be able to reach the dogsName.name property when I have determined the dogs.ID property. 
Thank you  for your help!
Sylvie

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your dev. environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: Please provide us with code of what you have tried so far, and explain why that isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the id, then you'll need to:

1. have access, somehow, to whatever *container* of dogs has the dog you want in it
2. use *some API* to filter on the `Id` - this could be simply `var dog = dogs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)`, or if the data is pre-indexed in a dictionary, something like `var dog = dogs[id];`

However! I think you should challenge the assumption that you only have the id. That's fine for *persisted* data; but once you have materialized the things into objects, it is hugely preferable to just store a *reference* to the target object directly, so you're not constantly doing lookups. So instead of thinking in terms of foreign key identifiers, you'd just have a `.Dog` property (or whatever)